# jList valueChanged event sets selected index to -1

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, indexoutofboundsexception, jlist

I am trying to manipulate data in my local sqlite db. I have a `jList` component which takes data from db.

First I define a `DefaultListModel` and then I am adding data in it with addElement method. Then I set `jList.setModel('model')`.. After I add or remove data from db `jList` is focused and it fires valueChanged event and sets `selectedItemIndex = -1`

And it outputs

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
>       at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:418)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:431)
>       at notdefteri.NotDefteri.listBaslikValueChanged(NotDefteri.java:75)
>       at notdefteri.NotDefteri.access$100(NotDefteri.java:20)
>       at notdefteri.NotDefteri$2.valueChanged(NotDefteri.java:125)
>       at javax.swing.JList.fireSelectionValueChanged(JList.java:1796)
>       at javax.swing.JList$ListSelectionHandler.valueChanged(JList.java:1810)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:184)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:164)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:211)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:405)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:415)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.removeSelectionIntervalImpl(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:576)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.clearSelection(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:420)
>       at javax.swing.JList.clearSelection(JList.java:2043)
>       at javax.swing.JList.setModel(JList.java:1677)
>       at notdefteri.NotDefteri.notlariBaslat(NotDefteri.java:55)
>       at notdefteri.NotDefteri.listBaslikMouseClicked(NotDefteri.java:292)
>       at notdefteri.NotDefteri.access$000(NotDefteri.java:20)
>       at notdefteri.NotDefteri$1.mouseClicked(NotDefteri.java:120)
>       at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6538)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

It keeps working but I don't know why or why not.

This is my code:

```
 package notdefteri;

 import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Calendar;
 import java.util.Date;
 import java.util.logging.Level;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;

 import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;

 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

 import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
 import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

 public class NotDefteri extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form NotDefteri
 */
SQLiteFunctions sqlf = new SQLiteFunctions();

ResultSet rs;
String textAreaSituation = "";
int selectedListIndex;
ArrayList<Not> siraliNotlar; 
int guncelIndex;

public NotDefteri() {
    initComponents();

    notlariBaslat();

}

public void notlariBaslat() {
    DefaultListModel<String> notBasliklari = new DefaultListModel<>();
    siraliNotlar = new ArrayList();
    rs = sqlf.notlariGetir();

    try {
        while (rs.next()) {

            notBasliklari.addElement(rs.getString("baslik"));

            Not siraliNot = new Not(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("baslik"), rs.getString("not"));
            siraliNotlar.add(siraliNot);

        }

        listBaslik.setModel(notBasliklari);
        listBaslik.setSelectedIndex(0);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NotDefteri.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

;


        private void listBaslikValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                        
            // TODO add your handling code here:

            if (!evt.getValueIsAdjusting()) {//This line prevents double events


                selectedListIndex = listBaslik.getSelectedIndex();

                **//It crashes on this line**
                Not not = siraliNotlar.get(selectedListIndex);

                try {

                    rs = sqlf.notGetir(not.getDbId());
                    txtAreaNot.setText(rs.getString("not"));
                    lblTarih.setText("Tarih : " + rs.getString("tarih"));
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(NotDefteri.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            }


        }  
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the entire stack trace of the exception, including any "Caused by" sections. That stack trace will tell you, and us, which line of code is causing the exception.

Comment: `at notdefteri.NotDefteri.notlariBaslat(NotDefteri.java:71)`  Line 71 is a blank line.  Please ensure the stack trace matches the code shown.

Comment: I tried to delete unnecessary lines. I have edited it now.

Comment: If you remove all selected rows from a JList, the JList no longer has any rows selected.  ListSelectionListeners are triggered both by selection and deselection.  Therefore, your code needs to handle the possibility that it is called when the JList has no rows selected.

Comment: but I have never delete all rows. At least I did not try. This problem occurs when I want to add or delete one row.